# Recipe formula in tidymodels

Tags: r, tidymodels, r-recipes

Imagine there is a formula for simple regression: y~f1+f2+f3, where f1 is a factor with A,B,C levels. f2 and f3 are numerics
Further i'm using following recipe:

```
recipe(y~f1+f2+f3, data) %>%
    step_dummy(f1) %>%
    step_log(f3)
```

Question. Eventually initial formula turns to `y~f1_A+f1_B+f1_C+f2+log(f3)`, right?

Question2. If I would have added

```
+step_pca(comp5)
```

it would become

`y~PC1+PC2+..PC5`?

Hope it make sense

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question

> Eventually initial formula turns to `y~f1_A+f1_B+f1_C+f2+log(f3)`, right?

Almost! The log step renames the variable (so the logged variables are just in column `f3`). The other parts are right.

Question 2:

> If I would have added
>
> +step_pca(comp5)
>
> it would become
>
> y~PC1+PC2+..PC5?

Yes(ish). The names that come out of `step_pca()` are designed to be sortable. If you have fewer than 10 components, then the above is right. If you have 11 to 99 components, then they are `PC01` ... `PC99`.

Finally, recipes don't just make a formula to do these computations (you probably didn't mean that but just to be sure). However, there is a little-known *formula method* that you can use on the recipes once it is prepared:

```r
library(tidymodels)

pen_rec <- 
  recipe(island ~ species + body_mass_g, data = penguins) %>% 
  step_dummy(species) %>% 
  step_log(body_mass_g) %>% 
  prep()

formula(pen_rec)
#> island ~ body_mass_g + species_Chinstrap + species_Gentoo
#> <environment: 0x125456170>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Week later realized I had a chat with Max Kuhn himself!, @topepo, i grew up on your books and packages:) You are one of those who pushing industry forward, thank you! hope one day i'll shake your hand